# I have ap-hotspot installed and working, but only HTTPS sites can connect

Tags: networking, linux-mint, android, wifi-hotspot

I installed ap-hotspot on my Linux Mint. Everything looks fine now, but only HTTPS sites can be connected from my Galaxy S4 phone such as Facebook, Google etc. When I want to connect to some other sites it is just not doing anything, just shows loading and dies due to timeout.

Here is my ap-hotspot debug log

```
* Stopping advanced IEEE 802.11 management hostapd
...done.
* Stopping DNS forwarder and DHCP server dnsmasq
* (not running)
update-rc.d: warning:  start runlevel arguments (none) do not match hostapd Default-Start values (2 3 4 5)
update-rc.d: warning:  stop runlevel arguments (none) do not match hostapd Default-Stop values (0 1 6)
Disabling system startup links for /etc/init.d/hostapd ...
Removing any system startup links for /etc/init.d/hostapd ...
/etc/rc0.d/K20hostapd
/etc/rc1.d/K20hostapd
/etc/rc2.d/K80hostapd
/etc/rc3.d/K80hostapd
/etc/rc4.d/K80hostapd
/etc/rc5.d/K80hostapd
/etc/rc6.d/K20hostapd
Adding system startup for /etc/init.d/hostapd ...
/etc/rc0.d/K20hostapd -> ../init.d/hostapd
/etc/rc1.d/K20hostapd -> ../init.d/hostapd
/etc/rc6.d/K20hostapd -> ../init.d/hostapd
/etc/rc2.d/K80hostapd -> ../init.d/hostapd
/etc/rc3.d/K80hostapd -> ../init.d/hostapd
/etc/rc4.d/K80hostapd -> ../init.d/hostapd
/etc/rc5.d/K80hostapd -> ../init.d/hostapd
update-rc.d: warning:  start runlevel arguments (none) do not match dnsmasq Default-Start values (2 3 4 5)
update-rc.d: warning:  stop runlevel arguments (none) do not match dnsmasq Default-Stop values (0 1 6)
Disabling system startup links for /etc/init.d/dnsmasq ...
Removing any system startup links for /etc/init.d/dnsmasq ...
/etc/rc0.d/K85dnsmasq
/etc/rc1.d/K85dnsmasq
/etc/rc2.d/K85dnsmasq
/etc/rc3.d/K85dnsmasq
/etc/rc4.d/K85dnsmasq
/etc/rc5.d/K85dnsmasq
/etc/rc6.d/K85dnsmasq
Adding system startup for /etc/init.d/dnsmasq ...
/etc/rc0.d/K85dnsmasq -> ../init.d/dnsmasq
/etc/rc1.d/K85dnsmasq -> ../init.d/dnsmasq
/etc/rc6.d/K85dnsmasq -> ../init.d/dnsmasq
/etc/rc2.d/K85dnsmasq -> ../init.d/dnsmasq
/etc/rc3.d/K85dnsmasq -> ../init.d/dnsmasq
/etc/rc4.d/K85dnsmasq -> ../init.d/dnsmasq
/etc/rc5.d/K85dnsmasq -> ../init.d/dnsmasq
* Restarting DNS forwarder and DHCP server dnsmasq
...done.
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

Comment: Is it this ap-hotspot? https://github.com/hotice/AP-Hotspot

Comment: I'm guessing there's a command line flag for it, but I don't know what it is without installing it. See what happens if you do `man ap-hotspot`

Comment: Looking at the source, I think you may instead have to edit `/etc/ap-hotspot.conf`

Comment: Thinking you'll be changing the `auth_algs` variable in that file, but I don't know what it'll change to.

Comment: Nope, that's not right. I'm guessing it'll be something in here: http://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/plain/hostapd/hostapd.conf

Comment: To explain, the program uses a Access Point service called `hostapd`; the link in the last comment was an example config file for that showing all the options that it takes. The config file for `ap-hotspot` is really just a config file for `hostapd`

Comment: Maybe has to do with the `Network Authentication Type` section of the hostapd config file?